# Ruby - producing a combination from two arrays *produces headache*

Tags: ruby, arrays, list, arraylist

What I'm trying to do is take an array of service names and apply a service response of either true of false to each.

Basically I'm getting an xml with a set of booleans for each of the services checked.  So for this example they all came back as true.

I put them into an array using Nokogiri like so:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
service_state = doc.css("HeartBeat Status").map(&:text)
```

This results in an array with 3 ["true"] items.
What I need to is apply each of them sequentially with an array I have in the code.

```
name = ['svc1', 'svc2', 'svc3']
```

To do this I used the following code:

```
status = [] ; service_state.each {|n| name.each {|l| status << [l,n]}}
status.each {|state| print state.to_s + "\n"}
```

This does what I want... sort of...

I do get an output of:

["svc1", "true"]
["svc2", "true"]
["svc3", "true"]

However, it repeats all the possible combinations.
When applying this to the actual array I have a total of 13 services that have a response 17 times so I end up with an array with 221 items.

Question: How do I do what I'm doing now but without repeating for each item in both arrays?

Thanks!

Comment: must they be in a multi-dimensional array? This seems like a good application for a map.

Comment: Your code can be written as status = service_state.product( name ) . It still won't do what you want - but there are good answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002198)

```
name = ['svc1', 'svc2', 'svc3']
status = ['true', 'true', 'true']

name.zip(status)
#=> [['svc1','true'], ['svc2','true'], ['svc3','true']]
```

Comment: Much cleaner vs. what I was doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
name.zip service_state
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a much more complicated answer than I needed.

This snippet gave me what I needed.  :P

```
status = [] ; service_state.each {|n| name.each {|l| status << [l,n]}}
status = status.uniq
status.each {|state| print state.to_s + "\n"}
```